# Referencing properties that are anonymous vs named functions

Tags: javascript

Reading John Resig's [Learning Advanced Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#13), I came across two slides that I don't completely understand.

Slide #13 - Reference a property that is an anonymous function. The second assert Fails.

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." ); // PASS

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = null; 

try { 
  samurai.yell(4); 
} catch(e){ 
  assert( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" ); // FAIL
}
```

Slide #14 - Reference a property that is a defined function. The second assert passes.

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "Works as we would expect it to!" ); // PASS

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = {}; 
assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." ); // PASS
```

The only difference here is that `yell` is a named function in slide 14. Why does the reference to a property defined as a named function remain even after setting the original object (`ninja`) to a new object (or even null)?

Comment: @Weedoze — No. Function declarations are hoisted. Function expressions are not. Function declarations *must* be named. Function expressions **may** be named. This question is about the difference between named and anonymous function expressions. There are no function declarations involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only difference here is that yell is a named function in slide 14.

No, that's not the only difference, nor the most important difference (though it's related to the important difference).

In the first one, note how `ninja.yell` is defined:

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
// ----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  } 
};
```

It explicitly uses `ninja.yell` within itself. So calling it will look up the variable `ninja` and then try to look up `yell` as a property on `ninja`.

Compare that with the definition in the second example:

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
// ----------------^^^^^^^^^
  } 
};
```

`yell` no longer uses the variable `ninja`, it just uses the in-scope identifier for itself (the one created by giving the function a name via a named function expression).

That's why when `ninja` is nulled out in the first example:

```
var ninja = null;
```

...the first one starts failing; you can't look up `yell` on `null`.

But when `ninaj` is replaced in the second one (I don't see why John didn't use `null` in both cases, but whatever):

```
var ninja = {};
```

...`yell` doesn't care, because it doesn't use `ninja`.

---

Side note: As of ES2015, neither version of `yell` is an anonymous function, even though the first one is created with an anonymous function expression. In ES2015, a function can get its name based on context, and one of the ways it gets a name is by being assigned to an object property within an object initializer. That doesn't help with this issue, though, since the name isn't an in-scope identifier within the function like it is when you use a named function expression.

Answer (score 1):

A function expression evaluates as a reference to the function.

```
foo = function () { ... };
```

The value of `foo` is now a reference to the function. You can copy that value anywhere you like.

---

A **named** function expression **also** create a local variable **inside itself** which has the same name as the function.

```
foo = function baz () { ... };
```

Here `foo` is a reference to the function in the global scope. `baz` is a reference to the function inside the scope of the function.

---

You can delete or overwrite the value of any variable or property without affecting any other variable or property that holds a copy of that reference.

The difference between your two cases is that the second one starts out with a second reference in a different variable and it (internally) uses *that* reference instead of the one in the wider scope.